# Game Server on Azure, Which CPU(VM size) should I choose?

Tags: azure

I currently use Standard DS 15v2 on Azure server but I currently experience huge lag because The game I want to run (Minecraft) does not support multi-core(Minecraft does its job on 1 core)

I was adviced that `a beasty 20 core cpu with a low clock speed is worse than a dual core with a high clock speed.`
so, Which VM size should I choose for `a high clock speed`server?

FYI, The Standard DS 15v2 offers me a Xeon E5

Comment: The CPU on DS 15v2 is E5-2673 v3 and it's frequency is only 2.4GHz

Comment: I think azure has faster CPU but am I wrong?

Comment: No right answer - just opinions. Off topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: @DavidMakogon what? are you joking?

Comment: @4c74356b41 Nope - this question is specific to Minecraft installations and picking a hardware config. Not in any way programming-related. And and not in any way answerable without the OP doing some benchmarking.

Comment: @DavidMakogon why not, whats wrong with MS benchmarks?

Comment: I don't think so @DavidMakogon
Microsoft officially recommend use StackOverflow and I was just asking the most high clock CPU Azure offer.
Yes, I talked about Minecraft but that is not the point

Comment: @Rui - The Azure page suggests StackOverflow for *programming* questions. And suggests ServerFault for infrastructure/networking questions. But regardless of what the Azure page suggests, questions still need to follow the guidelines of StackOverflow / ServerFault (these are not Microsoft-owned Q&A properties).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've found [benchmarks from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-compute-benchmark-scores?toc=%2fazure%2fvirtual-machines%2fwindows%2ftoc.json), according to the article they are run on all cores, but you could deduce single core performance from that.

Also this [table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-sizes):

```
SKU Family          ACU/Core
Standard_A0         50
Standard_A1-4       100
Standard_A5-7       100
Standard_A1-8v2     100
Standard_A2m-8mv2   100
A8-A11              225*
D1-14               160
D1-15v2             210 - 250*
DS1-14              160
DS1-15v2            210-250*
F1-F16              210-250*
F1s-F16s            210-250*
G1-5                180 - 240*
GS1-5               180 - 240*
H                   290 - 300*
```

ACUs marked with a `*` use Intel® Turbo technology to increase CPU frequency and provide a performance boost. The amount of the boost can vary based on the VM size, workload, and other workloads running on the same host.